# Drupal Migration Issue - Install Screen Showing Instead of Site

Tags: drupal, failed-installation

We are migrating a bit of an old Drupal installation (6.x) from one hosting platform to another.  Unfortunately due to political issues we are unable to upgrade the Drupal Core or modules prior to migration (eg. Needs to be done yesterday!).

Having copied all files across to the new server (in the identical location) and also re-imported the required databases and modified the settings.php file when we access the site all that is displayed is the Drupal installation screen.

I'm guessing it's some sort of path issue but there were no paths in the settings.php file.  Following another post on here I realised that I hadn't brought across the .htaccess files but I have now done that and still no change.

Can anyone suggest anywhere I should be looking or perhaps a step I have missed?

We are moving from an Apache server to a LiteSpeed Web Server but I doubt that is an issue.

Any help anyone can provide would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Why do you doubt the move from Apache to LiteSpeed is an issue? Drupal is quite particular about the way in which it expects url rewriting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install screen is normally shown when Drupal can connect to the database server (so credentials seem to work), but does not find the existing Drupal database itself.

So you should check your database connection settings in settings.php and verify that it references the correct database. You should also verify that the database got migrated correctly, and that the user used by the Drupal instance has the proper access rights for the migrated database (although the latter would result in a different error message, IIRC).